# How can I set number in pagination laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My query in controller is like this :

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
           ->paginate(10);
```

My view is like this :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Usename</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $key => $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! ++$key !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $user->username !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $user->email !!}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    {{ $users->links() }}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It works

But,

For example I have 15 data

On the page 1, the number column like this :

> 1
>
> 2
>
> ...
>
> 9
>
> 10

When I click page 2, the number column like this :

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

I want when click page 2, the number column display like this :

> 11
>
> 12
>
> 13
>
> 14
>
> 15

How can I do it?

Comment: Why `->links()` ? You can use `->render()`

Comment: @Alex Slipknot, It's the same

Comment: Well, its very strange behavior. Normally it works like expected. Maybe you've overwrote your pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code need to update like:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>Number</th>
       <th>Usename</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       ...
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach($users as $key => $user)
       <tr>
           <td>{{ ($users->currentpage()-1) * $users->perpage() + $key + 1 }}</td>
           <td>{!! $user->username !!}</td>
           <td>{!! $user->email !!}</td>
           ...
       </tr>
   @endforeach
   {{ $users->links() }}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Great. It works. But I modify like this : `<td>{{ ($users->currentpage()-1) * $users->perpage() + $key }}</td>`. So, the number start from 1